# How to do bitwise operations for hexadecimal in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have Apoc to support lots of functions in Neo4j. But I am wondering whether we can do bitwise operations on hexadecimal in Neo4j.

My plan is to firstly convert two strings to two hash values by using `apoc.util.md5`. And then I suppose to use `apoc.bitwise.op` to do bitwise operation on these two hash values. However, `apoc.util.md5` gives a hexadecimal string, while `apoc.bitwise.op` can only take Integer. Further, as we know, md5 hash produces 128 bit result, which is out of range of Integer. So I am wondering whether there is any other approach can implement the bitwise operation on hexadecimal string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline for one way to do that for non-shifting bitwise operations (but it may be better to write your own plugin to do it directly instead):

1. Split the 32-character-wide input hex string into 4 separate 8-character-wide strings. Similarly split the other operand (also assumed to be a 32-character-wide input hex string).
2. Use [apoc.convert.toInteger](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#conversion-functions) to convert each 8-character-wide hex string (after prefixing each with "0x") to an integer.
3. Perform the bitwise operation on each corresponding pair of integers.
4. Use [apoc.text.hexValue](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_overview_text_functions) to convert each integer result back into hex, and prepend enough "0" characters to the front to reach a width of 8 characters.
5. Concatenate the 4 hex strings back into a single 32-character-wide hex string.

In Cypher, assuming that the input 32-character-wide hex string, the bitwise operation (e.g., '|'), and the other operand are passed as the [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) `$input`, `$operation`, and `$operand`:

```
WITH [i IN RANGE(0, 24, 8) |
  "0000000" + apoc.text.hexValue(
    apoc.bitwise.op(
      apoc.convert.toInteger("0x" + SUBSTRING($input, i, 8)),
      $operation,
      apoc.convert.toInteger("0x" + SUBSTRING($operand, i, 8))))
  ] AS x
RETURN REDUCE(r = "", s IN x | r + SUBSTRING(s, LENGTH(s)-8)) AS res;
```

In fact, the above can actually be done in a single concise clause:

```
RETURN REDUCE(r = "",
  s IN [i IN RANGE(0, 24, 8) |
    "0000000" + apoc.text.hexValue(
      apoc.bitwise.op(
        apoc.convert.toInteger("0x" + SUBSTRING($input, i, 8)),
        $operation,
        apoc.convert.toInteger("0x" + SUBSTRING($operand, i, 8))))] |
  r + SUBSTRING(s, LENGTH(s)-8)
) AS res;
```